# Branch.io INSTALL, OPEN standard events and custom events are not logging

Tags: android, branch.io

We are implementing deep-linking for an Android application(multi-flavor) according to branch documentation described here https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/.
     After integration tested with IntegrationValidator.validate(this), it passed.  We have tested the following scenarios:
 1. Shared deep-link via Gmail, after that it opens the correct application if it is installed already, otherwise it goes to playstore URL. Working as expected.
2. After sharing we are getting the below response from branch

```
    I/BranchSDK: posting to https://api.branch.io/v1/event  
    Post value = {some data}   
    BranchSDK: returned {"branch_view_enabled":false}
```

Issue: In Branch dashboard events like: OPENS, INSTALL, SHARE, REOPEN etc are not updating.Only LINK CLICKS is updating.